# How can I manually add a keyboard shortcut to a Shortcut Action Service directly via the system files, without going through the System Prefs GUI?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, sirishortcuts, macos-sonoma, system-preferences

I want to set a keyboard shortcut for my shortcut action to Ctrl-Shift-Esc. Normally Esc key shifts focus to parent scope, but this happens when setting keyboard shortcut in System Preferences. Blatantly fails in Shortcuts app. Therefore, there is no way to have Esc key in keyboard shortcut. However, throught bug abuse on an older macOS version, I was able to set Ctrl-Shift-Esc and it worked. I take responsibility for accidentally resetting it. The point is, it is possible to have the keyboard shortcut as such. I assert that there is some database that stores the keyboard shortcut for shortcut actions. Therefore, I also assert that I can edit it to configure said keyboard shortcut. I appreciate your time.

[image: sqlite database on shortcuts]
[image: files related to the matter]
[image: failure within system prefs]
[image: failure within shortcuts app]

I have attempted to set the shortcut in System Prefs, Shortcuts app, dug around in Finder, almost found it (found `GlobalPreferences.plist` as shown) but mind-boggling structure of Sqlite database discourages me. I have attempted lots of Googling and came to the conclusion I should ask StackOverflow.